# Unable to connect to internet through my WiFi

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

I am new in Ubuntu`s world.

I wrote `lspci` and
the output I received was;

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

I have also wrote `sudo rfkill list` and the output was;

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN

Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no

1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN

Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no

2: hci0: Bluetooth

Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu server or Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu desktop

Comment: Follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) tutorial and see if it helps.